# How to change colors and shades of images used in the app in android

Tags: android, imageview, alpha

In my Android App, I am using one image in background and also using some images of arrow. I have added the image in xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/none"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to change the image colors from the Java Code with some provided color codes. The image background will recieve one color and the texture/shades/actual image portion will receive another color. I heard something about getting the alpha of the image and apply colors on the image checking where is white and where is gray. Not sure how to do that.

For example, I am including an image of the arrow. I want to change the background from white to different colors and also the arrow from to another color. Please suggest.

[image]

Also, is there any way to change the colors if the image is in the alpha mode where the background is transparent?

Answer (score 2):

If you make the image background transparent (the white part), so you have only what you call the "image portion" visible, than you can change the background by either [`setBackground(Drawable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), [`setBackgroundColor(color)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) or [`setBackgroundResource(resource)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) (since the background will be visible through the transparent parts of the image).

To change the actual image color, use [`setColorFilter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int%29), there are three different versions of this method, so you should be able to find one that suits your needs.

---

To change a **single image used as a background**, make the base image red and green (or some other different colors that don't use several color channels. Black and white would not work) and get it as a [`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). This is since the Drawable can have a `ColorFilter`, just like the `ImageView`. Give it a [`ColorMatrixColorFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html).

If the background part is *red*, and the foreground *green*, you can then use a [`matrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html) such as

```
[bR, aR, 0, 0,
 0, bG, aG, 0, 
 0, 0, bB, aB,
 0, 0, 0, bA,
 aA, 0, 0, 0]
```

where

```
background R,G,B,A = bR, bG, bB, bA
foreground R,G,B,A = aR, aG, aB, aA
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for the images within imageview. That was a great help! Could you suggest anything when I am using an image as background of a RelativeLayout or TextView?

Comment: @MSI I added an example for that too.

Comment: Thank You! I am not sure how I will apply the matrix here. The color code I will receive from back end and will apply whatever color code I receive into the image of background. The background image is not with black and white and already set as Background Resource. I was something like this but not very successful yet:                         LinearLayout MyView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
  MyView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgpetals);
  Drawable dr = MyView.getBackground();
  dr.setAlpha(0);

Comment: For example; if you get the color codes background color `bg = #FF450067` and foreground color `fg = #FF0065AF`, insert it into the matrix: `float[] matrix = [Color.Red(bg), Color.Red(fg), 0, 0, 0, Color.Green(bg), Color.Green(fg), 0, 0, 0, Color.Blue(bg), Color.Blue(fg), 0, 0, 0, Color.Alpha(bg), Color.Alpha(fg), 0, 0, 0]`. Then create a ColorMatrix instance with this matrix, and apply to the ColorMatrixColorFilter, and use the drawables `setColorFilter()` method to apply the ColorMatrixColorFilter.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, I am interpreting your question as if you have a *single image* with two colors (such as black and white in the arrow picture), and want to be able to change those colors to something else independently of eachother.

Comment: Thank you! I tried in this way, getting blank background. LinearLayout MyView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);  MyView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pet);
  Drawable dr = MyView.getBackground();
  dr.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
Color.red(Color.parseColor(tC)), Color.red(Color.parseColor(tT)), 0, 0, 0, 
Color.green(Color.parseColor(tC)), Color.green(Color.parseColor(tT)), 0, 0, 0, 
Color.blue(Color.parseColor(tC)), Color.blue(Color.parseColor(tT)), 0, 0, 0, Color.alpha(Color.parseColor(tC)), Color.alpha(Color.parseColor(tT)), 0, 0, 0 })));

Comment: here tC = #644E37, tT = #FC0500. And the original image is with light blue in the background and deep blue in the actual image. So it's basically two colors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43360/discussion-between-msi-and-jave)

Comment: @Jove, for the record does setColroFilter change the color of JUST THE FOREGROUND (ie, the src) or ALSO the background?  (Example, your background may be say a gray square, your src is a large white dot. I want to color only the dot.)  Thanks for the answer answer here!